# xmlstarlet not working for simple selection based on child string value

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xmlstarlet

I am working on XML file like

```
<bookstore> 
   <book category="cooking"> 
       <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title> 
       <author>adc</author> 
       <year>2005</year> 
       <price>30.00</price> </book> 
   <book category="children"> 
       <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title> 
       <author>xyz</author> 
       <year>2005</year> 
       <price>29.99</price> </book> 
</bookstore>
```

Using xmlstarlet on linux

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m 'bookstore/author [1]' -n books.xml
```

Would give output as `"adc"`, but how can I find the field when I already know the value?

Like I know author tag has value `"adc"`. 
How should I find `bookstore/author [x]` the `x`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of searching I found the answer and leaving it in someone else stumbles across same

To select value by field in xmlstarlet use

```
xmlstarlet -t -c 'bookstore/book[author="adc"]' -n books.xml
```

Here bookstore/book is complete path of node which contains author 
[author=value] is used to select nodes only where author has specific value 
And books.xml is your xml file

I am sure others can explain better but hope you find this of some help

Comment: Your XPath says to select all `bookstore/book` elements with child `author` elements equal to child `adc` elements.  You're missing quotes around `adc`.  Further, there are many Q/A about how to use XPath in XMLStarlet; see duplicate link for just one example.

Comment: @kjhughes Thnx for help, I have corrected the answer and I added it as I couldn't make use of duplicates